# What are the best practices for Product Images in CEF?

Tags: image, product, chromium-embedded

I know that CEF has an image resizer that can automatically fix image sizes, but do we have the best practices when it comes to Image sizes/resolution/etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

The size of images are less important than the shape of them. The images in the catalog will be a square shape. So any images that are rectangular may not render as well in the catalog.

The higher resolution the image, the better it will look. The lower the resolution, the faster an image will render on the page. There is a balance between those two. Obviously having 3 GB image file will not work but you don't want pixilated images either. Typically this is a data issue that can be addressed by the client as the project progresses.

If that answer isn't sufficient for the client, tell them to shoot for images in a close to square shape between 1 and 5 MB and then decide whether they would like to change at a later time for more performance or high resolution images.

Comment: Adding that the images are only pulled at full size on the product details page. Other locations, like the Catalog or Cart will use Image Resizer to pull only smaller, resized images.